# Classic Analytics to Universal Analytics event tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm going to switch from the Classic Analytics to Universal Analytics.

As I understand, I need to edit my event tracking code accordingly?

My current event tracking code look like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'About us', 'Contact form']);
```

What do I need to write in order to make it work with Universal Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

The Universal Analytics syntax for tracking Custom Events would be:

```js
ga('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'About us', 'Contact form');
```

You can check the official documentation about Custom Events here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

You might also be interested in the official guide to upgrading from the Classic to Universal Analytics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs